# os.walk() vs os.scandir()

Tags: python, os.walk

**[os.scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir)** claims to be a better directory iterator and faster than `os.walk()`. It became a part of the stdlib for Python 3. Working in production environments, what are the things to consider when moving from `os.walk()` to `os.scandir()`?

Comment: You could just install 3.5 and use `walk`, which will use the `scandir` algorithm if I recall correctly.

Comment: But what when you are using any 2 version (2.7) and want to use os.scandir?

Comment: Python 2.7 is no longer considered production-ready -- no security updates -- so questions about it in a "working in production environments" context are arguably no longer relevant. @bossi, keep in mind that editing an old question brings it back to the front page. You might want to focus on questions that are relevant and valuable today.

Answer (score 1):

I once used os.scandir() in Python 2.7. It kept on crashing because of weird unicode characters. (`ù ỳ ǹ` and the likes). Switched back to os.walk() and everything was fine. I would suggest you test that if it's a concern.

Appart from that it really is faster, especially on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, you do not move from [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir). They do different things. `os.scandir` may be used instead of `os.listdir()` in cases where you needed to call [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) several times afterwards and could give a performance benefit by avoiding those calls. Also, `os.scandir`, being an iterator, uses less memory.

With acceptance of [PEP 471](https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/) in Python 3.5+, `os.walk` now uses `os.scandir` instead of `os.listdir()` internally, so you have the mentioned performance benefit.